# Sobreescribir archivo en SharePoint en C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Tengo un método que inserta un archivo en SharePoint usando

```cs
RootFolder.Files.Add(file)
```

así que quiero tener la opción de **sobreescribir el archivo** sabiendo sólo la URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El método [`RootFolder.Files.Add`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/ms428630.aspx) tiene una sobrecarga que recibe un Booleano que especifica cuándo sobrescribir archivos con el mismo nombre.

#### [SPFileCollection.Add method (String, Byte[], Boolean)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/ms428630.aspx)

```cs
public SPFile Add(
    string urlOfFile,
    byte[] file,
    bool overwrite
)
```

Parámetros:

> - **urlOfFile**
>     Tipo: System.String
>     La URL relativa del archivo.
> - **file**
>     Tipo: []
>     Un array de bytes que contiene al archivo.
> - **overwrite**
>     Tipo: System.Boolean
>     `true` para sobreescribir un archivo con el mismo nombre; `false` no sobreescribe.